# Implementing hoverIntent for Drop Down Menu (coming from click_event)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a drop down menu that was originally activated by `click_event`, however I want to now implement `hoverIntent` in order to make the menu drop.

The issue I am having now is being able to use the menu, because whenever I invoke the menu now, once I leave the area that activates the menu, the menu closes.

JavaScript:

```
    function setupUserConfigMenu() {
        $('.user_profile_btn').hoverIntent(
            function (event) {
                $('#user_settings_dropdown').animate({height:['toggle', 'swing']
            }, 225);
            },
            function (event) {
                $('#user_settings_dropdown').animate({height:['toggle', 'swing']
            }, 225);

            })
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <li>
        <a href="<%= "#" %>" class="user_profile_btn" title="Your profile page"><%= truncate(current_user.full_name || current_user.name, :length => 28) %>
          <div class="arrow_down"></div></a>

        <ul id="user_settings_dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="<%= current_user.get_url(true) %>">
              <%= image_tag current_user.get_thumb_url, :size => "30x30" %>
              <div>
                <%= truncate(current_user.full_name || current_user.name, :length => 40) %>
                <br>
                View profile
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <div class="grey_line"></div>

          <li class="settings_list_item">
            <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %>
          </li>
          <li class="settings_list_item">
            <%= link_to "About", "/about" %>
          </li>
          <li class="settings_list_item">
            <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by implementing a setTimeout() and clearTimeout(). Here's the code:

JavaScript:

```
    $('.user_profile_btn').hoverIntent(
        function () {
            $('#user_settings_dropdown').delay(150).animate({height:['toggle', 'swing']
            }, 225);
        },
        function () {
    })

    var settings_dropdown_timer;

    $('#user_settings_dropdown').mouseout( function () {
        settings_dropdown_timer=setTimeout( function (){
            $('#user_settings_dropdown').hide();
        },2000)
    });

    $('#user_settings_dropdown').mouseover( function (){
        clearTimeout(settings_dropdown_timer);
    });


    $('#user_settings_dropdown').bind("clickoutside", function () {
        $('#user_settings_dropdown').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try using a delay on your hoverout.

```
 $('#user_settings_dropdown').dealy(1000).animate({height:['toggle', 'swing']
        }, 225);
```

Comment: While, yes this does work somewhat, the menu disappears after the delay whether the user's cursor is in the menu or not. I'm looking for something to keep the menu active when the user's cursor is hovering in the menu. Thanks for the suggestion though, I can use .delay() for other task I have :)

Answer (score 0):

What I've found to be the best bet in this situation is to enclose the menu trigger and the menu body in a wrapper and apply the hoverIntent to that. When your menu is hidden, the wrapper is the size of the trigger element. When the menu is shown, the wrap will include all of the visible menu as well, allowing the user to click anywhere in the menu.

Here's a stripped down example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/irobinson/HeDSR/2/

html

```
<div id="menu-wrap">
<a href="#" class="user_profile_btn" title="Your profile page">
    <div class="arrow_down">Down arrow</div>
</a>
<ul id="user_settings_dropdown">
    <li><a href="#"><div>View profile</div></a></li>
      <div class="grey_line"></div>
      <li class="settings_list_item">Item a</li>
      <li class="settings_list_item">Item b</li>
      <li class="settings_list_item">Item c</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>​
```

javascript

```
$('#menu-wrap').hoverIntent(function () {
    $('#user_settings_dropdown').show();
},
function () {
    $('#user_settings_dropdown').hide();
});​
```

css

```
#user_settings_dropdown{display:none;}
#menu-wrap{width:100px;}​
```

Comment: Alternatively (or additionally) you can also add a hide() animation on the hoverOut of the actual menu as well. That will cover the case where they hover over the trigger, then down to the menu, and back up to the trigger (may feel more natural) Example: http://jsfiddle.net/irobinson/HeDSR/4/

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I ended up going a different route using setTimeout and clearTimeout. Thanks for you solution though :)